# Can I use a semicolon before because?

Tags: sentence-construction, conjunctions, punctuation

It is safe to write either "Because ..., ..." or "... because ...". However, sometimes I find that if one sticks to the rule of no-comma-before-because, then the whole sentence gets extremely long. For example, instead of writing

> The sequence is not convergent because there is no real number $l$ such that for every $\epsilon > 0$ there is an $N \geq 1$ such that $|x_{n} - l| < \epsilon$ for all $n \geq N.$"

to me it looks better to write

> The sequence is not convergent; because there is ...".

I thus wonder if it is a common American usage to use the sign ";" to separate the sentences. For example, is it legitimate to write "I am healthy; because everyday I get up early."?

Comment: A couple questions: (1) What makes you think Americans would punctuate this differently than Canadians, Australians, New Zealanders, or writers in the UK? (2) What is this _no-comma-before-because_ "rule" you speak of? Here's [one reason](http://www.chicagomanualofstyle.org/qanda/data/faq/topics/Commas/faq0018.html) to use a comma; here are [five more](http://www.dailywritingtips.com/5-calls-for-a-comma-before-“because”/).

Comment: you could drop the 'because' and it still makes sense with a semi-colon. Do you have an example of a long sentence with no commas?

Comment: Your title asks about *since,* but it doesn't appear in your question. Please clarify.

Comment: @JonMarkPerry: Yes, they are mathematical ones. When one writes up a proof, often times one seems to encounter this issue...

Comment: I don't think mathematicians go a whole lot on grammar anyway, so I wouldn't worry about it.

Comment: @JonMarkPerry: Yeah, but, since I am not an English native speaker, I am not that sure of the "safe" zone! I have not yet had that kind of feeling or intuition for English!

Comment: @Chou; you almost answered your own Q: Yeah, but **,** since I am not...

Comment: Moreover, the reason why I did not make an essential example in companion to my question is that I am afraid some people may hurriedly close my question...

Comment: @JonMarkPerry: Indeed, I am not sure of my use of comma. Thus I would like to ask. Besides, how do you know that the correctness is not due to probability?

Comment: the answer isn't in any books, because there is no (written) law about it

Comment: @Chou It's perfectly reasonable to close a vague/without-sufficient-context  question. It's obvious a sentence in, presumably, a Math.SE post caused your confusion. Why not provide it here?

Comment: @MARamezani: Not at all. I am asking for the sake of my own writing. Just want to have a general principle in mind, so that I will not just "guess" the timing to use comma or not.

Comment: To me, it is very normal to run into a situation where people cannot provide a specific example but you can still sense what he or she is trying to ask. Personally I came across lots of such issues. But, certainly, I do not expect that everyone else is going to have this in-others'-shoes mindset.

Comment: Unfortunately, it's too hard (i.e. making this post very broad and yet, the broader answer will hardly be able to cover everything) to give a general principle. There isn't a limit to the senses a comma can give to a sentence or a couple of sentences. And yes, everyone runs into such situations, and a lot.

Comment: @Chou Maybe this post will be fine if you add examples concerning this sentence of yours: *However, sometimes I find that if one sticks to the rule of no-comma-before-because, then the whole sentence gets extremely long.* As I said before, this whole thing is assumingly case-relevant.

Comment: @MARamezani But I am afraid then I would incur another issues..., which is the original concern of mine...

Answer (score 1):

Semicolons are normally used to combine two complete sentences, so you shouldn't use a semicolon before "because". The long part of your sentence is what comes after "because". Adding a comma or a semicolon won't help that.